# How to fix ValueError in pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am moving an application from a classic Tkinter GUI to a Django cloud-based application and am receiving a

`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'bool'>`

when trying to run a function which calls on pandas.

`Exception Location:    C:\Users\alfor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer, line 232`

I have not tried much because I cannot find this same Error in searches.

I do not believe this function even runs AT ALL because my media folder is not getting a new directory where the file would be saved.. but I could be wrong.

The beginning of the function that is having issues looks like this:

```
def runpayroll():
    man_name = 'Jessica Jones'

    sar_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Stylist_Analysis.xls')
    sar_file2 = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Stylist_Analysis.xls')
    tips_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Tips_By_Employee_Report.xls')
    hours_wk1_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Employee_Hours1.xls')
    hours_wk2_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Employee_Hours2.xls')
    retention_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/SC_Client_Retention_Report.xls')
    efficiency_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Employee_Service_Efficiency.xls')

    df_sar = pd.read_excel(sar_file,
                           sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=4)
    df_sar2 = pd.read_excel(sar_file2,
                            sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=4)
    df_tips = pd.read_excel(tips_file,
                            sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=0)
    df_hours1 = pd.read_excel(hours_wk1_file,
                              header=None, skiprows=5)
    df_hours2 = pd.read_excel(hours_wk2_file,
                              header=None, skiprows=5)
    df_retention = pd.read_excel(retention_file, sheet_name=0,
                                 header=None, skiprows=8)
    df_efficiency = pd.read_excel(efficiency_file, sheet_name=0,
                                  header=None, skiprows=5)
```

The only code I have changed from the rest of this function is this which I am assuming does not matter because it is only a file location..

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/media/payroll.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

and instead of asking the user for a file save location using tkinter I used...

```
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f, content_type=guess_type(file_path)[0])
        response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
        return response
```

Expected results are to open a few excel sheets, do some work to the dataframes, and to spit out an excel sheet to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need change for each file from:

```
sar_file = os.path.isfile('media/reports/Stylist_Analysis.xls')
```

to:

```
sar_file = 'media/reports/Stylist_Analysis.xls'
```

because [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile):

> Return **True** if path is an existing regular file. This follows symbolic links, so both islink() and isfile() can be true for the same path.

Comment: Excellent explanation! And thank you! Now off to the next error! :D